# How to hide content of binding using office.js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The Word desktop app allows to hide/display the text by togggling 'Hidden' property in Font properties.

The same can be achieved by setting `<w:vanish />` property using `binding.setDataAsync(data, Office.coercionType.OOXML)` which sets `data` to a binding. It works in Word desktop app but doesn't work in Word Online. The XML can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Vivekananda-Athukuri/084721057e8a3a220ec0474128a0ab24).

I tried setting data as html and use `display: none;` as style to the root element and that's not working.

Are there any other ways to hide text with Office.js that works in both Word desktop app and Word Online?

Comment: Word on-line simply doesn't support "hidden" font formatting. So, no, it's not possible using font formatting. If you expect people to work with the document in Reading (vs Editing) view you could put the information in a conditional IF field, then it would be hidden. But in the editing view the user sees a [Field] placeholder...

Comment: Yes, we are looking for an alternative way to hide the text completely without the placeholder.

Comment: The only other thought that occurs to me would be to put this text into content controls and remove the text from the content controls (substituting a space, perhaps) if the document is opened in the on-line version of Word. Store the text in a Custom XML Part inside the document so that it can be restored if/when the document is then opened in the desktop version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If the binding is the only text in the line, replacing it with an empty string or space leaves a blank line in the document. As you said, the only option might be to save the text in custom XML and "hide" the text and get rid of the binding. To restore it, is to parse the document and look for the custom XML and create a binding back in its place.