# Marking text as "hidden" with the OfficeJS API in a MS Word Add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I was wondering if there is a way to "toggle" a section of text (in a ContentControl element) to be visible/invisible through an Add-In using the OfficeJS API.

The approach I would take would be to mark the text within a section as "hidden" (ie right click on text in MS Word -> font -> hidden). This property can be accessed through [Office VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.hidden), however the property doesn't seem to exist in the [Javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=office-js)

Am I just missing something obvious? Or is there an alternate approach one could take? I don't want to simply delete the section as it may need to be restored at a later stage, and applying a custom style that is preconfigured with the "hidden" font property would result in a loss of original styling when turning the section back on again, ie:

```
...

var templateElement = context.document.contentControls.getByTag(id);
context.load(templateElement);

return context.sync()
   .then(function () {
      templateElement.items.forEach(function (x) {
      x.style = show_contents ? "Normal" : "Custom_Style_With_Hidden_Property_Checked";
   });
});

...
```

Comment: Can you try setting `ContentControl.appearence` to "Hidden"?

Comment: The reason the Office JS api doesn't have this is because Word On-line doesn't support the hidden font formatting. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312862/how-to-hide-content-of-binding-using-office-js

Comment: Setting the appearence to hidden just hides the fact that there's a content control box, not the ACTUAL content of the field, which is what I'm after.

And cheers for the clarification on why the API doesn't support the feature, that makes sense... but is rather tragic, given that the rather unsavoury alternative would be to directly edit the OOXML.

Comment: I agree, Seb. Note for using Stack Overflow: In order to let someone know you've replied to them in comments you need to precede their screen name with a @ symbol. For example: @Seb Otherwise there's no notification. I'm only seeing this because I occasionally check back...